# R markdown assignment js-variable

Tags: r

I'm create .rmd file, how I can assignment string into `<script></script>` snippet

````
```{r results='asis'}
 string<-"test"
```
<script>
var js_string = "......"
</script>
````

Comment: Perhaps "var js_string = `r string`" (backticks around `r string`)?

Comment: var js_string = r [string] - its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Roman Luštrik"
date: "24. avgust 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r results='asis'}
 string<-"test"
```
<script>
var js_string = `r dQuote(string)`
</script>
````

[image]

Comment: @DavidArenburg embrace the darkness.